# Bokeh is behaving in mysterious way

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, data-visualization, bokeh

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import * 
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
```

## prepare data

```
N = 300
x = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi, N)
y0 = np.sin(x)
y1 = np.cos(x)
output_notebook()

#create a column data source for the plots to share
source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = x, y0 = y0, y1 = y1))

Tools = "pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset, save, box_select, lasso_select"
```

## create a new plot and add a renderer

```
left = figure(tools = Tools, plot_width = 350, plot_height = 350, title = 'sinx')
left.circle(x, y0,source = source )
```

## create another plot and add a renderer

```
right = figure(tools = Tools, plot_width = 350, plot_height = 350 , title = 'cosx')
right.circle(x, y1, source = source)
```

## put the subplot in gridplot and show the plot

```
p = gridplot([[left, right]])
show(p)
```

[image]

**something is wrong with sin graph. Don't know why 'Bokeh' is behaving like this.But if I write y's into  Double or single quotation marks/inverted commas then things work fine**

```
left.circle(x, 'y0',source = source )

right.circle(x, 'y1', source = source)
```

## put the subplot in gridplot and show the plot

```
p = gridplot([[left, right]])
show(p)
```

[image]

Things I tried to resolve the problem

1) Restarted my notebook . (Easiest way to solve problem)

2) Generated the output into new window.

3) Generated plot separately instead of grid plot.

Please help me out to find out the reason behind the scene.

Am I doing something wrong ?
Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure multiple glyphs to share data from a single `ColumnDataSource`, then you always need to configure the glyph properties with the *names* of the columns, and ***not*** with the actual data literals, as you have done. In other words:

```
left.circle('x', 'y0',source = source )

right.circle('x', 'y1', source = source)
```

Note that I have quoted `'x'` as well. This is the correct way to do things when sharing a source. When you pass a literal value (i.e., a real list or array), glyphs functions like `.circle` automatically synthesize a column for you as a convenience. But they use defined names based on the property, so if you share a source between two renderers, then the second call to `.circle` will overwrite the column `'y'` column that the first call to `.circle` made. Which is exactly what you are seeing.

As you can imagine, this behavior is confusing. Accordingly, there is an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2056) to specifically and completely disallow passing in data literals whenever the `source` argument is provided explicitly. I can guarantee this will happen in the near future, so if you are sharing a source, you should always and only pass in *column names* (i.e. strings).